# Trim UIImageView to fit content

Tags: ios, uiimageview, crop

Does anyone know how I could trim a UIImageView of some image with surrounding transparency down to just barely fit the content by cropping off the edges?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this category:

https://github.com/Clstroud/UIImage-Trim

Here is a usage example from their docs:

> UIImage-Trim Category for trimming transparent pixels of an UIImage
>   object.
>
> How to use
>
> Add the UIImage+Trim files to your project. Include UIImage+Trim.h in
>   the files where you want to trim your images.
>
> Trimming is pretty straightforward:
>
> ```
> [yourImage imageByTrimmingTransparentPixels];
> ```
>
> Optionally, you may want to consider any non-opaque pixels as being
>   transparent (for instance, cropping out a light drop shadow). This can
>   be achieved by using the alternate method:
>
> ```
> [yourImage imageByTrimmingTransparentPixelsRequiringFullOpacity:YES];
> ```
>
> Additionally, if you merely desire to know the UIEdgeInsets of the
>   transparency around the image, you may want to use the following:
>
> ```
> [yourImage transparencyInsetsRequiringFullOpacity:YES];
> ```
>
> This call works based on the same principles as the "advanced" trim
>   method, with the boolean dictating whether non-opaque pixels should be
>   considered transparent.